# checking one checkbox checks all the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to check all the other checkboxes if one checkbox is checked. My code

```
<tr>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportModuleName" runat="server" name="report"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="particulrs"></td>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportAdd" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportEdit" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportDelete" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportView" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportPrint" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="othr"><span><input type="checkbox" id="chkReportActivity1" name="reports" /></span></td>
</tr>
```

On check of the checkbox named report.I want to check all the checkboxes with the name reports.

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Where `#selectall` is the id of Your "report" checkbox and `.case` is the cssclass for all the chekboxes you want to get selected on clicking `#selectall`

You can also use `prop` function instead of `attr` for newer version of jquery

Comment: hope you have added reference to the jquery file

Comment: Use this Link it may help you
http://www.wiseguysonly.com/2010/01/15/select-and-unselect-all-checkboxes-with-jquery/

Comment: That link proposes a needlessly complicated way to implement this. Your own answer is much better, though it requires some changes to the OP's html before it will work.

Comment: This ones working fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/mdAbw/
Other possible reasons could be other jqueries anyways
trying placing the above script at the very bottom of body tag
or use  `$(document).ready(function()` instead of `$(function()` for the very first line only...

Answer (score 2):

OK:

```
$('input[name="report"]').click(function(){
   $('input[name="reports"]').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

On click of the "report" checkbox, all of the "reports" checkboxes will be set to the same state as "report". If you want it to only work one-way, i.e., if unchecking the "report" checkbox should not uncheck the others, then do this:

```
$('input[name="report"]').click(function(){
   if (this.checked)
       $('input[name="reports"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

The above should go in a document.ready handler and/or in a script block that appears after all of the checkboxes.

If you're using an old version of jQuery you'll need to use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`.

Simple demo (also shows how to use document.ready): http://jsfiddle.net/eHLcS/

Comment: It is not working .I want the report to be on checked not on click.

Comment: I've added a simple demo (based on your html) showing it in action. For a checkbox, the click event occurs when the box is checked or unchecked - even if done via the keyboard. But as I stated, you need to put the above in a document.ready handler and/or in a script block after the actual checkboxes.

Comment: I can't understand where i am going wrong i have implemented the same way as you showed.

Comment: Is your ASP code generating html similar to what I put in the demo? What version of jQuery are you using? (If older than 1.6 use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`.)

Comment: I think there might be some problem with the asp:Checkbox because it generates different name then what i specified

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="report"]').change(function() {
    $('input[name="reports"]').attr("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

attach followingfunction in all checkboxes's onclick event (who has name=='report')

```
function CheckAllReportCheckboxes()
{
    var elm = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
        if (elm[i].type == "checkbox" && elm[i].name == 'report') {
                elm[i].checked = 'checked';
        }
    }
}
```

Remember it will not work for unchecking the checkboxes.