# checking one checkbox checks all the checkbox in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to check all the other checkboxes if one checkbox is checked. My checkbox is an array. If one checkbox is checked i want all the checkbox in that row to be checked. My code

```
<tr>
  <td class="small">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportModuleName" runat="server" name="report"></asp:CheckBox>
  </td>
  <td class="particulrs"></td>
  <td class="small">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportAdd" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox>
  </td>
  <td class="small">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportEdit" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox>
  </td>
  <td class="small">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportDelete" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox>
  </td>
  <td class="small">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportView" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox>
  </td>
  <td class="small">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportPrint" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox>
  </td>
  <td class="othr">
    <span><input type="checkbox" id="chkReportActivity1" name="reports" /></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

On check of the checkbox named report.I want to check all the checkboxes with the name reports. The checkbox chkReportModuleName is an array. When it is clicked i want only the checkboxes in that row to be checked.

The jquery which i have tried is as follows:

```
 $('input[name="ctl00$MainContent$chkTransModuleName"]').click(function () {
   $('input[name="trans"][i]').attr("checked", this.checked);
   $('input[id="MainContent_chkTransAdd"]').attr("checked", this.checked);
   $('input[id="MainContent_chkTransEdit"][i]').attr("checked", this.checked);
   $('input[id="MainContent_chkTransDelete"][i]').attr("checked", this.checked);
   $('input[id="MainContent_chkTransView"][i]').attr("checked", this.checked);
   $('input[id="MainContent_chkTransPrint"][i]').attr("checked", this.checked);
 });
```

It runs but i want the only those checkboxes to be checked which are in that row.

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking one checkbox checks all the checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073554/checking-one-checkbox-checks-all-the-checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

assuming the name `ctl00$MainContent$chkTransModuleName` is correct

```
$('input[name="ctl00$MainContent$chkTransModuleName"]').click(function () {
    var chk = !!this.checked;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.small > input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', chk);    
});
```

Comment: This will also toggle the `chkReportActivity1` checkbox, which the OP didn't want.

Comment: all my checkbox are checked except my delete checkbox. I can't understand as it is similar to the other checkbox

Comment: This does not toggle the chkReportActivity1 checkbox as the class is othr. I used this $(this).closest('tr').find('.othr > input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', chk); for it but still it is not checked. All my other checkboxes are checked except delete

Comment: could you post a fiddle with that markup as it is receveid on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, give the checkboxes `CssClass` to make them easier to identify:

```
<tr>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportModuleName" CssClass="reportModule" runat="server" name="report"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="particulrs"></td>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportAdd" CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportEdit" CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportDelete" CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportView" CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="small"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkReportPrint" CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" name="reports"></asp:CheckBox></td>
    <td class="othr">
        <span><input type="checkbox" id="chkReportActivity1" name="reports" /></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then you can use this jQuerycode:

```
$('.reportModule').click(function () {
    var $el = $(this), $parentTR = $el.closest("tr"), checked = $el.is(":checked");
    $(".checkbox", $parentTR).attr("checked", checked);
});
```

This code uses the closest `tr` element as a context in which to look for the related checkboxes to toggle.

Comment: Then it must be something else in your code causing an error, as it works fine in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mP6EY/